# Create a new column with dummy value replacement

Tags: r

I have a DF with chr values of "Champions", "2nd", "3rd", and "NA".

I want to create a new column to my DF and assign dummy attributes of 1,2,3,4 respectively.

There are 1757 obs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46773808/generate-a-dummy-matrix-from-multiple-factor-columns

Comment: Alternatively, https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fastDummies/vignettes/making-dummy-variables.html